# Printing image from array

Tags: php, jquery, concrete5

first off, I'm extremely new to PHP.

I'm using Conrete5, and I have a new template to an image slider. This is what I'm using:

```
http://codepen.io/altitudems/pen/KdgGLG
```

There's a placeholder image, which I'm trying to replace by grabbing the first image set in the block itself. Here is my view file from the actual block:

```
<?php defined('C5_EXECUTE') or die("Access Denied.");
$navigationTypeText = ($navigationType == 0) ? 'arrows' : 'pages';
$c = Page::getCurrentPage();
if ($c->isEditMode()) { ?>
    <div class="ccm-edit-mode-disabled-item" style="width: <?php echo $width; ?>; height: <?php echo $height; ?>">
        <div style="padding: 40px 0px 40px 0px"><?php echo t('Image Slider disabled in edit mode.')?></div>
    </div>
<?php  } else { ?>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(function () {
        $("#ccm-image-slider-<?php echo $bID ?>").responsiveSlides({
            prevText: "",   // String: Text for the "previous" button
            nextText: "",
            <?php if($navigationType == 0) { ?>
            nav:true
            <?php } else { ?>
            pager: true
            <?php } ?>
        });
    });
});
</script>

<div class="ccm-image-slider-container ccm-block-image-slider-<?php echo $navigationTypeText?>" >
    <div class="ccm-image-slider">
        <div class="ccm-image-slider-inner">

        <?php if(count($rows) > 0) { ?>
        <ul class="rslides" id="ccm-image-slider-<?php echo $bID ?>">
            <?php foreach($rows as $row) { ?>
                <li>
                <?php if($row['linkURL']) { ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $row['linkURL'] ?>" class="mega-link-overlay"></a>
                <?php } ?>
                <?php
                $f = File::getByID($row['fID'])
                ?>
                <?php if(is_object($f)) {
                    $tag = Core::make('html/image', array($f, false))->getTag();
                    if($row['title']) {
                        $tag->alt($row['title']);
                    }else{
                        $tag->alt("slide"); 
                    }
                    print $tag; ?>
                <?php } ?>
                <div class="ccm-image-slider-text">
                    <?php if($row['title']) { ?>
                        <h1 class="ccm-image-slider-title"><?php echo $row['title'] ?></h1>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <?php echo $row['description'] ?>
                </div>
                </li>
            <?php } ?>
        </ul>
        <?php } else { ?>
        <div class="ccm-image-slider-placeholder">
            <p><?php echo t('No Slides Entered.'); ?></p>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Here is my gallery view file:

```
<a class="gallery-launcher" href="#gallery1"> // Location of the image
   <div class="overlay">
        <div class="overlay-content">
            <button class="btn btn-default">Open Gallery</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
<div class="gallery inactive" id="gallery1">
    <div class="gallery-item">
        //Fullscreen gallery code here
    </div>
</div>
```

Where it says // Location of the image is where I need to have the first image set. I can't figure out what I'd put there? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the concrete5 file helper to get the file path, like this for example:

```
$f = File::getByID($row['fID']);
$relpath = $f->getRelativePath();
```

In general I suggest that you read more about the [concrete5 file functions](https://www.concrete5.org/documentation/developers/5.6/files/files-and-file-versions/) to understand more how it works: